# How do I fetch an element from a webpage in Google Apps Script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am making a geography quiz with HTML and Google Apps Script, and I need to take the answer input from the web page. I tried fetching the link and parsing the element to XML, but but it said I had to close some sort of meta tag. As far as I know, I didn't put in any meta tags. Here is the Script:

```
function doGet() {
    var URL = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzxrT9Tf_W080kpYq26exEC5O3NrI-EUOZssckOVow-9_9yKkBW/exec').getContentText();
    var Parse = XmlService.parse(URL);
    var GetRoot = Parse.getRootElement();
    var ParseBack = HtmlService.parse(GetRoot);
    var ansInDiv = getElementById(URL, 'a1', 'a2', 'a3');
    return(ansInDiv);
}

// send
function send() {
    var EmailAddress = "#########@gmail.com";
    MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, "Geo Quiz Answers", doGet());
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>
        Geography Quiz
    </title>
  <base target="_top">
  <font face="Verdana" size="20px">
    Welcome to the Geography Quiz.
  </font>
  <font face="Verdana">
    Begin whenever you are ready. 
  </font>
  <script>
    function RunSend() {
        google.script.run.send();
    }
  </script>
  <div id="answers">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p>
      q1
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="a1">
    <p>
      q2
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="a2">
    <p>
      q3
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="a3">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="RunSend()" value="Submit">
        Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</html>
```

How do I get the script to fetch the element and send it in an email?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the approach you use seems a bit strange to me, I would do it simply like this :

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setTitle('quizz').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME); 
}

function send(result) {
    var EmailAddress = "-------@gmail.com";
    MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, "Geo Quiz Answers", result);
}
```

and in html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>
        Geography Quiz
    </title>
  <base target="_top">
  <font face="Verdana" size="20px">
    Welcome to the Geography Quiz.
  </font>
  <font face="Verdana">
    Begin whenever you are ready. 
  </font>
  <script>
    function RunSend() {
      var a1 = document.getElementById("a1").value
      var a2 = document.getElementById("a2").value
      var a3 = document.getElementById("a3").value
      var result=a1+"-"+a2+"-"+a3  
      google.script.run.send(result);
    }

  </script>
  <div id="answers">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p>
      q1
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="a1">
    <p>
      q2
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="a2">
    <p>
      q3
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="a3">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="RunSend()" value="Submit">
        Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</html>
```

[Demo here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyE7BXQWAXmnEcoY1yCAy_df0zk9MeV3pL3ki9GvdBNge5TrJg/exec)

Comment: Thanks, but it says "getElementById is not defined". I think there is something wrong with the <!DOCTYPE html> declaration.

Comment: did you try de memo ? is the problem occurring  with the demo or with your implementation ? I doubt there might be error on such a basic setup.

Comment: No, I fixed it. I just had to make a new version of the application.